# how to echo day,month,year separately in PHP

Tags: php

Consider the following code.

```
    <html>
    <form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name1">
    <input type="date" name="date1">
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="sub">
    </form>
    </html>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {  
    echo $_POST['date1'];//line 11
    echo "<br>";
    echo $_POST['name1'];
    }
    ?>
```

line 11 display the date i have selected.But i want to echo the day,month,year separately.
I am new to php. Help me please.Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you show your date format?

Comment: Start from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: This largely depends on the format you expect the date to be submitted through

Comment: The date format is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @aashnisshah, The date format should conform to RFC[3339]. 
See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html
or here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it appears that your date should post back in the following format: [yyyy-mm-dd](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html)

To split the date up into its individual elements, you need php's [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

First, however, you'll need to pass $_POST['date1'] through the [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) since [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) wants a unix timestamps as a parameter.

```
$date_timestamp = strtotime($_POST['date1']);
```

Once you've got your input date converted to a timestamp, you can use [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to extract elements (year, month, day).

```
$day = date("d", $date_timestamp);
$month = date("m", $date_timestamp);
$year = date("Y", $date_timestamp);
```

Read more on [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to see different output formats.